# SUMIF with conditions on Dates in R

Tags: r, spotfire

### I have the following table

```
**A**  | **B**  | **C** |**D** | **E**|
:----: | :----: | :----:|:----:|:----:|
1/1/17 | 3/1/17 |4/1/17 | H    |0.4   |
1/1/17 | 3/1/17 |4/1/17 | H    |0.2   |
2/1/17 | 4/1/17 |5/1/17 | V    |0.6   |
3/1/17 | 5/1/17 |6/1/17 | V    |0.8   |
4/1/17 | 5/1/17 |7/1/17 | H    |0.6   |
4/1/17 | 6/1/17 |7/1/17 | H    |0.2   |
```

---

The idea is to use Spotfire if not then R within soptfire. Unfortunately, don't have a base code as I'm not sure on how I can compare a single row's data from the Unique Dates to an entire column of dates in A,B & C and sum values form another column E. Do have the initial portion from where I can possibly extract unique Date values from. Don't think its as useful but included it in here.

```
library(reshape2) 
mydata<-melt(dates,id=c("D")) 
mydata$value<-ymd(mydata$value)

Looking for the result as in the table below using R code
 1. Column with Unique list of dates from columns A,B & C above
 2. Sum of Column E where Column A dates <= Unique Dates value for each 
    columns A,B&C from the above table.
 3. Only Sum filtered by column D value of 'H' only
```

OR 
Is there a way to get a graph in Spotfire with Unique Dates as the X axis and the sum on the Y axis without having to create a separate table as below using R within Spotfire.

### Result

```
**Unique Dates**  | **Sum for A** |  **Sum for B** | ** Sum for C**|
    :----:        |     :----:    |     :----:     |     :----:    |
    1/1/17        |      0.6      |       0        |       0       |
    2/1/17        |      0.6      |       0        |       0       |
    3/1/17        |      0.6      |      0.6       |       0       |
    4/1/17        |      1.4      |      0.6       |       0.6     |
    5/1/17        |      1.4      |      1.2       |       0.6     |
    6/1/17        |      1.4      |      1.4       |       0.6     |
    7/1/17        |      1.4      |      1.4       |       1.4     |
```

Example:
For Unique Date of 3/1/2017 in Column A it is 0.4+0.2=0.6
that is values corresponding to 1/1/2017 in A only as 2/1/2017 has "V" in the Column D. Similarly for 2/1/2017 it remains 0.6 as the only values for H are being added.

Comment: I get the idea that this is an *R* question, so your `spotfire` tag is perhaps unnecessary. Are you using base R, `dplyr`, `data.table`, or something else? I agree with Rich Scriven's comment, please provide your code, otherwise it appears like you are being lazy and asking us to do all of your work for you.

Comment: @r2evans - The idea is to use Spotfire if not then R within soptfire. I am using base R. Unfortunately, don't have a base code as I'm not sure on how I can compare a single row's data from the Unique Dates to an entire column of dates in A,B & C and sum values form another column E. Do have the initial portion from where I can possibly extract unique Date values from. Don't think its as useful but included it in here.
library(reshape2)
mydata<-melt(dates,id=c("D"))

mydata$value<-ymd(mydata$value)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Just as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556705/using-countif-on-dates-in-r), it would be beneficial to provide consumable sample data. (The answers there did that job for you, though it should really be done in the original question. You are more likely to get feedback and answers if you make it easier.)

Comment: @r2evans I agree, will go ahead and add it in my question. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get those results for Sum for A? Specifically, 5/1/17 to 7/1/17... when there is no value attributed to A in the original? Can you explain?

Comment: Sure, as 1/1/17, 2/1/17, 3/1/17 & 4/1/17(in column A) <= 5/1/17 & 7/1/17 (Unique Dates Column) we add all values corresponding to them. And then considering we are filtering column D for "H" we exclude values for 2/1/17 & 3/1/17. We get 0.4+0.2+0.6+0.2 = 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data in the Note at the end try this. No packages are used.

```
nms <- names(DF)[1:3]
fo <- E ~ A + time

DFH <- subset(DF, D == "H")
r <- reshape(DFH, varying = list(nms), times = nms, dir = "long")
xtabs(fo, aggregate(fo, r, sum))
```

giving the following -- note that the output in the question does not seem to correspond to the input in the question so the following necessarily differs:

```
A          A   B   C
  1/1/17 0.6 0.0 0.0
  2/1/17 0.0 0.0 0.0
  3/1/17 0.0 0.6 0.0
  4/1/17 0.8 0.0 0.6
  5/1/17 0.0 0.6 0.0
  6/1/17 0.0 0.2 0.0
  7/1/17 0.0 0.0 0.8
```

This could also be expressed as a magrittr pipeline where `nms` and `fo` are as above:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
   subset(D == "H") %>%
   reshape(varying = list(nms), times = nms, dir = "long") %>%
   { aggregate(fo, ., sum) } %>%
   xtabs(formula = fo)
```

**Note:** Input data:

```
Lines <- "
A      | B      |   C   |D     | E
:----: | :----: | :----:|:----:|:----:
1/1/17 | 3/1/17 |4/1/17 | H    |0.4   
1/1/17 | 3/1/17 |4/1/17 | H    |0.2   
2/1/17 | 4/1/17 |5/1/17 | V    |0.6   
3/1/17 | 5/1/17 |6/1/17 | V    |0.8   
4/1/17 | 5/1/17 |7/1/17 | H    |0.6   
4/1/17 | 6/1/17 |7/1/17 | H    |0.2   "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE,
   comment.char = ":", sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you got the results in your post, but this should be able to be done with a transformation in `Spotfire`

1. `File > Add Date Tables > Add (drop down on right) > From Current Analysis: "Name of Your Original Data Table"`
2. `Transformations > Unpivot > Add`
3. `Columns to pass through: D, E`
4. `Columns to transform: A, B, and C`
5. Click `OK`

[image: Add Data]

[image: Un Pivot]

Then, you just need to add a cross table... Here is how you set up the axis

1. Horizontal: `[Category]`
2. Vertical: `[Value]`
3. Cell values: `Sum([E])`

That will give you these results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks this is helpful to know how you can unpivot in Spotfire. But Sum of E wouldnt really do a if Date in A <= Unique Date then sum values in E. I included an example in my question above hoping that can help.

Comment: As the idea is to add values in E with a corresponding value of "H" in Column D. So 0.6 corresponding to 2/1/2017 and 0.8 corresponding to 3/1/2017 have been ignored.